# Android SMS show contact name by recipient_ids

Tags: android, sms, android-contacts

The code snippet below returns basic SMS conversation data:

```
Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse( "content://mms-sms/conversations?simple=true"), null, null, null, "normalized_date desc" );
if(cursor.moveToFirst())
  String recipient_ids = cursor.getString(3);
```

My question is that how can I get a phone's contact data given that recipient_ids? In this case I need to retrieve the contact number and contact display_name.

Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This seems to crash on a Galaxy Note 2 with Android 4.3. The error is `Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: normalized_date (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM threads ORDER BY normalized_date desc` . How can you determine if the normalized_date column does not exist? I have tested this on other versions of android without an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public String getContactData(String id){
  String number;

  Cursor phones = fa.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ id, null, null); 
    if(phones.moveToFirst()) { 
      number = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));       
    } 

  phones.close();
  return number;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

This is, what's working in my app:

```
private String getContactNumber(final long recipientId) {
    String number = null;
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(ContentUris
            .withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/canonical-address"), recipientId),
            null, null, null, null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        number = c.getString(0);
    }
    c.close();
    return number;
}
```

The contact numbers are saved in some table called `canonical-address`.
It was kind of buggy a few years ago. Updates on the contact did not propagate through this table properly. But I think that's fine now.

You basically need to parse the (list of) ids into single ids. Then query the database for each of them.
You could use one single query for all ids together, though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but its giving me this error

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unrecognized URI:content://mms-sms/canonical-address`

Comment: Please try the uri with an appended /. It is working in my apps for 5years now. ;-) try to replace the contenturi thing with a selection of `"_id="+recipientId`

Comment: giving this exception in some of the phones                                             Fatal Exception: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException
no such column: data1 (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT data1 FROM canonical_addresses WHERE _id=1127